# Disabling syslogd messages

Tags: centos6, syslogd

As I am working with the terminal, I see a lot of messages every some seconds saying that

```
Message from syslogd@compute-0-0 at Jul 24 18:38:57 ...
 kernel:[  723.595032] [Hardware Error]:     MC4_STATUS[-|CE|MiscV|-|AddrV|CECC]: 0x9c0240006b080813

Message from syslogd@compute-0-0 at Jul 24 18:38:57 ...
 kernel:[  723.595042] [Hardware Error]: Northbridge Error (node 0): DRAM ECC error detected on the NB.
```

There are a lot of discussions for that and I have to go to find the buggy DRAM DIMM.

Until then, I want to disable the flood of messages on the terminal. I didn't find "**how to disable the online syslogd messages**".

Any idea for that? The OS is Centos-6.

Answer (score 3):

Check `/etc/rsyslog.conf` for `RULES` and change below line:

```
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console
```

To

```
kern.*                                                 /dev/null
```

Then restart rsyslogd:

```
/etc/init.d/rsyslog reload
```

Comment: That line it currently commented. Do you mean I have to uncomment that?

Comment: Edited the answer. Try and let me know.

Comment: Has no effect!! I even tried with `restart` instead of `reload`

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/351387/how-to-stop-kernel-messages-from-flooding-my-console ?